# How to get max date value in each individual employee?

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I tired to this query please help me.

```
select max(cr.`CARD_RECHARGE_ID`),cp.`FULL_NAME` as userName , cr.`CHARGE_DATE` as lastRechargeDate,cr.`CUSTOMER_ID`
from nettxs_communication.customerprofile cp
LEFT JOIN nettxs_communication.cardrecharge cr ON cr.`CUSTOMER_ID` = cp.`CUSTOMER_ID` 
group by cr.`CUSTOMER_ID` ORDER BY cr.`CHARGE_DATE`;
```

[image]

Comment: Please clearify what you exactly want to do.

Comment: i have order table in which multiple employee records date wise and 
i want get last records of employee from last dates in table.

Comment: I was make this query but  can't actual data show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To what i understand from your comments you want to pick the latest entry from `cardrecharge` for each `CUSTOMER_ID`, which relates to [greatest-n-per-group](/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group)

```
select cp.CUSTOMER_ID,
    cp.FULL_NAME,
    cr.CHARGE_DATE as lastRechargeDate,
    cr.CARD_RECHARGE_ID
from customerprofile cp
left join cardrecharge cr ON cr.CUSTOMER_ID = cp.CUSTOMER_ID
join (
    select CUSTOMER_ID, max(CHARGE_DATE) CHARGE_DATE
    from cardrecharge
    group by CUSTOMER_ID
) cr1 on cr.CUSTOMER_ID = cr1.CUSTOMER_ID and cr.CHARGE_DATE = cr1.CHARGE_DATE
```